# How do I include hidden HTML elements in a string - javascript - datatables - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a script which will take the `html()` of an element (table), and write it to a text file.

The table which I take this from is drawn using the [datatables](https://datatables.net/) jQuery plugin, for pagination, and sorting.

The JS will only include the `displayed` elements in the string. Is it possible to include all `hidden` elements too, so that all of my table rows are included in this string, and not just the rows on the `active` page?

```
function saveRangeReview(){

    var htmltosave = $("#rangereviewtable").html();
    var filename = "testreview";

    var postdata = { rangereviewdata: htmltosave,
                     filename: filename};
    $.ajax({
          url: "rangereview.save.php",
          type: "post",
          dataType: 'html',
          data: postdata,
          success: function (response) {

              console.log(response); //only includes 10 currently displayed rows

              },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

              console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go trough the dataTables API to do this, luckily there is methods for retrieving all aspects of a table - also the underlying DOM nodes.

Here is an example, it reproduces the entire table as plain HTML markup

```
$('#generateHTML').on('click', function() {
  var domNodes = '';
  table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    domNodes += this.node().outerHTML
  });
  //<thead> section
  html = table.table().header().outerHTML
  //add <tbody> with all DOM nodes
  html += '<tbody>'+domNodes+'</tbody>'
  //<tfoot> section
  html += table.table().footer().outerHTML
  //wrap into <table>
  html = '<table>'+html+'</table>'

  console.log(html)
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/krqL519o/**